# android studio debugger verry slow

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

i recently switched to Kotlin and to android studio Electric Eel (2022.1.1 Patch 1).

Now i do not know if it is Kotlin or the new version of studio but ever sinds that point in time my debugger is verry slow in evaluation values of variable.
And with slow i mean: after waiting for 10 minutes is was still collecting data.
In short this is unworkable.
I am hoping this is not a Kotlin feature because i am just getting used to it after a month of swearing to my PC :-)

anybody any idea?

[image]

**Update 15-04-2023**
I have a bug report with google (for some time now) but i seems they are ghosting me ;-) 
[enter link description here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/269765403)

Answer (score 2):

You can try and invalidate your caches then restart your IDE. Alternatively check the location of your breakpoints, they might be the issue

Comment: the invalidate caches made no difference. i had my breakpoint on a if-statement which i think i verry normal but when i put it on a different line it worked as expected.
you answer is the one i needed  so thank you for this but i still think the debugger is crappy if it cannot handle a breakpoint on an if-statement.

Comment: Initial i marked this answer the THE answer but have to change it  back.
I still is a verry useful comment but the debugger is unworkable. if i do not set the breakpoint on the exact correct line everything will freeze and there is no logic in where to put it. And then even if i have it on a line where the debugger doesn't freeze up i cannot look at the value of any var becuase it will then freeze again.
I really mis Java. never had this problem back then. why did google stop with java????